# Codeigniter overriding show_404 cant load view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

file:MY_Exceptions.php,

```
  class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
      public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
      }

     public function show_404($page = ''){
       //from helper, helper's loading..correctly. so are libs
       $data=common_site_data(); 

       $CI->load->view('site/templates/header',$data);                    
       $CI->load->view('site/home/404',$data);
       $CI->load->view('site/templates/footer',$data);

    }

 }
```

But no views are loading..! Not even the errors/error_404.php..!
What's the heck? Can anyone help this out?

Comment: where this is file is located ?

Comment: In application/core. I had to call output method of CI for the views to be dispatched finally. It's solved now. Thanks for your answer.